# Create one collection for each user vs create one collection for all user

Tags: php, mongodb, nosql

I'm using PHP and MySQL for a social network system under Ubuntu environment.

I have MySQL table named `user_feed` , in this table I save feeds as feed_id for each user  my table structure in MySQL is:

```
    |user_feed_id | user_id | content_id | seen |
```

and I have table `user_follow` that contain data followed by every user , so each user has set of record for what he/she followed content.

Table structure:

```
follow_id | user_id  | content_id |
```

In user_feed table I have more than 170 million records, and every user has set of records and in `user_follow` table I have more than 500 000 record.

I currently work to migrate from MySQL to MongoDB., so I need to convert this table to collection in MongoDB. I think to build my collection for `user_feed` and `user_follow` as follow:

Create collection for each user and this collection has three document, one for follow ids and another one for feed_ids, so when I handle user profile I will run my query for one collection for each member:

Each collection name is refer to user_id like :

```
user_id_1 as collection name

            { user_id: '1'}
            {
                feed_ids: [
                 { content_id: '10', 'seen' : 1 },
                 { content_id: '11', 'seen' : 0 },
                 { content_id: '12', 'seen' : 1 },
                 { content_id: '13', 'seen' : 1 }
              ] 
            }
            {
             follow_ids: [
                 { content_id: '10' },
                 { content_id: '20'},
                 { content_id: '23'},
                 { content_id: '24'}
             ]
           }


user_id_2 as collection name

            { user_id: '2'}
            {
                feed_ids: [
                 { content_id: '14', 'seen' : 1 },
                 { content_id: '15', 'seen' : 0 },
                 { content_id: '16', 'seen' : 0 },
                 { content_id: '17', 'seen' : 0 }
              ] 
            }
            {
             follow_ids: [
                 { content_id: '22' },
                 { content_id: '23'},
                 { content_id: '24'},
                 { content_id: '25'}
             ]
           }
```

so if I have **70 000 user** then I need to create **70 000 collection** in **MongoDB**

and I have another option to create it like :

all user feeds for one **collection** and each user has one document inside collection like:

```
{
        user_id: '1',
        feed_ids: [
            { content_id: '10'},
            { content_id: '11'},
            { content_id: '12'}
        ],

        follow_ids: [
            { content_id: '9'},
            { content_id: '11'},
            { content_id: '14'}
        ]
    }
```

and the data in these tables grow very significantly and I need the collections and documents to be able to do all operation like **(insert, update, select,..)**

My feed_ids and follow_ids is grow very very significantly and my queries is :

```
select content_id from user_feed where user_id =1 limit 10 offset 20;

update user_feed set seen = 1 where user_id =1

select count(content_id) from user_feed where seen = 0;

select content_id from user_follow where user_feed_id =1 limit 10 offset 20;

insert into user_feed (user_id,content_id,seen) values (1,23,0);
```

is the first option is the optimal solution for my use case or the second one?

Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't create one collection per user. I would have a collection for a purpose and create document per user. Also if you know your schema and know what you expect to put inside those documents you can use pre-allocated method to avoid "Swiss Cheese" and grow your document without fragmenting your space. I would suggest you to take a look at this book: "MongoDB Applied Design Patterns" chapter 8 is about Social Networking. You can find pretty good schema examples plus some codes that you might be interested. One more thing, avoid complexity, it just ruins your project stability!

Answer (score 2):

One collection for each user would never scale due to `nssize` limitations (2GB) since this would mean you are limited to 3 million users per database (assuming that database only holds users...). Once you start spanning such a thing over multiple databases as well then you are really starting to get into implementation problems.

This setup has no performance benefits since the main benefit would be the lock and that is on database level. I would still think my first point in the paragraph above would hold over the lock even if it was implemented per collection. As an added note you would get inefficient use of space due to the way that MongoDB treats a single document when updating unbound arays, it will create a "swiss cheese" effect and cause massive fragmentation lowering performance further.

So just based on that, no, I would not make one collection per user.

Comment: @jetawe Another note, MongoDBs strength is to shard huge collections horizontally through a cluster of shards, use this strength instead of trying to avoid it

Comment: so according to your answer do you think that the second option is the best fro my use case.

Comment: @jetawe In tems of thinking about using only one collectio yes; the schema...that would be another question and we would probably need a lot more info

Comment: what info do you need for the schema, please help me.

Comment: @jetawe Prolly an indea of what size the feeds and feeds_ids and what queries are done and what those arrays are....hmm maybe more

Comment: I provide you with my queries in question body.

Comment: @jetawe I would look into separating that schema to be honest

Comment: sorry , I don't understand , do you mean with "separating" that the second one is the best , so one collection for all users

Comment: @jetawe No I men separate out the feed_ids and feeds into separate collections, they will most likely cause problems as such documents

Comment: TL;DR - 1st design is trying to shoe horn RDBMS/Normalisation into a document based database. 2nd design is more mongo-ish. Use profiling to prove the theory (or if you're too lazy search the mongo log for slow queries). also make use of indexing (in particular search for multikey indexes) for your feeds and follow keys.